# How to remove duplicate elements from an array in Swift 5?

Tags: swift

I have an array of custom objects, a.k.a users, and some of them are duplicates.

How can I make sure there is only one of each element? No duplicates.
Also, what's the most efficient way?

```
var users: UserModel = [UserModel]()
```

Comment: What is the basis of the duplicate check? This question is lacking a lot of important details.

Comment: How about checking for a duplicate **before** inserting a new item? Or use a set anyway, if possible.

Comment: This has been [asked and answered multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+array+remove+duplicates). Both set-based and order-preserving methods have been provided in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most efficient way if you don’t care about maintaining the original order in the array

```
let uniqueUsers = Array(Set(users))
```

Comment: Of course this assumes that `UserModel` properly conforms to `Hashable`.

Comment: A good reason to make it conform :-)

Comment: I've made it conform to Hashable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using an array you want to use a set? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set

Comment: This could be a good answer if you stated it an answer rather than another question.  Additionally you should provide the essential parts of the link in your answer in case the link breaks or changes in the future.